# Confused by extra wire on Legrand dimmer

Tags: electrical, wiring, dimmer-switch

Replacing 3 dimmers and one single pole switch in a 4 gang setup with Legrand dimmers and a Single Pole switch.

Original wiring by licensed electrician.

Existing dimmers have R,B,R/W(Not connected)and ground wires.

The Legrand products are frame grounded, eliminating the ground wire for each dimmer. The Legrand dimmers have wires labeled Common (B), Neutral (W), 3-Way (R) and I-Pole (R).

I understand the wiring except for the I-Pole wire. The existing setup does not provide an extra wire going to each dimmer. What do I do, if anything, with the I-Pole wire?

Comment: What make and model are these dimmers, and where are you on this planet?

Comment: Also, I take it there is a neutral bundle (big bundle of white wires) in the back of the box, no?

Comment: Legrand Adorne Whisper Tru-Universal Dimmer.

Comment: Located in Florida.

Comment: Yes, Big bundle of neutral wires in the back of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Common = LINE, 1-Pole = LOAD

For your new dimmers in a single pole installation, the Common wire connects to the LINE side wiring (whatever wires the old dimmer's black wire connected to, most likely), while the 1-Pole wire connects to the LOAD side wiring (whatever wire the old dimmer's red wire connected to, most likely).  The 3-Way wire is left unused/insulated, just like the red/white wire on the old dimmer, and the Neutral wire is bundled in with the rest of the neutral wires in the back of the box.  Note that on the Legrand adorne line, the *frame* has a ground wire that must be connected to the box ground wires in order to ground the dimmer properly; simply connect it to whatever ground wire was grounding the old dimmer.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Just what I needed. I was unfamiliar with the I-Pole designation and I don”t the “Let’s see how this works” thing. The Documentation included with the dimmers was actually not helpful in the way it was written.